# Datatables child row not showing

Tags: jquery, datatable, parent-child

I am following this blog post on Datatables [Sliding Child Rows](http://datatables.net/blog/2014-10-02) but I can't get my rows to show when clicked.. I just want to be able to show the child row when the first column is clicked. What am I doing wrong?

My jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#products').DataTable({
      "lengthMenu": [[20, 50, 100, 500, -1], [20, 50, 100, 500, "All"]],
      "columnDefs": [{ className: "details-control", "targets": [ 0 ] }]
    });
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#products tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        $('div.slider', row.child()).slideUp( function () {
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        } );
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format(row.data()), 'no-padding' ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');

        $('div.slider', row.child()).slideDown();
    }
  } );
</script>
```

And then the table itself with some dummy data to show

```
<table id="products" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered 
  table-condensed">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th> </th>        
      <th> </th>
      <th><a>TITLE</a></th>
      <th><a>ASIN</a></th>
      <th><a>PRICE</a></th>
      <th><a>SKU</a></th>
      <th> </th>
      <th> </th>
     </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody class="product-index">

   <% @merchant.products.each do |product| %>
     <tr>
       <td>+
         <div class="slider" name>
           <table>
             <tr>
               <td>
               ... Data to be shown ...
               </td>
             </tr>
           </table>
         </div>
       </td>
       <td><%= check_box_tag('sellersku[]', product.sellersku) %></td>
       <td><%= product.title %></td>
       ...
   <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: When you inspect the element after clicking, is there an error output on the console? Also, why is there a '+' character after the the `<td>` in `<tr> <td>+ <div class="slider" name>` ?

Comment: No, no error.. It just doesn't do anything.. frustrating.. and the '+' is just a placeholder for now.. Until I get an icon.. just something to click on..

Comment: Can you provide the fiddle from [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all you lack a `table` reference, i.e `var table = $('#products').DataTable()`.

You also need to actually insert the content of the child row. dataTables child rows is inserted dynamically - you can not use static content as your markup indicates. Typically you would use a function that return content for the child row, very often called `format(data)` (and you do actually have a reference to such function in the copied code) where `data` is the parent row itself. But you can do it in anyway you like. Below just your markup from the question :

```js
function format(data) {
    return '<div class="slider" name>'+
           '<table>'+
             '<tr>'+
               '<td>'+
               '... Data to be shown ...'+
               '</td>'+
             '</tr>'+
           '</table>'+
         '</div>'
}
```

These two changes make your code work, including the slide effect -> **http://jsfiddle.net/LmudsL36/**